generating function with conditions
Q)
In how many ways can 6 balls be taken out of a bag containing 4 identical blue, 5 identical white and 6 identical green balls, provided that the number of green balls cannot be more than the number of white and blue balls combined.
My try: from my knowledge of generating functions i wrote the above as:
$$ (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$$
the order of the brackets are for blue, white and green respectively. now i need to know the coefficient of x^6, but im not sure if the last brackets (for the green ones) have the correct terms.
Is this expression correct, if not then how will i write it?
